# Every convex equilateral polygon inscribed to a circumference is a regular polygon.

Tags: geometry

I know that all regular polygons can be inscribed into a circumference and that not all convex equiangular polygons that can be inscribed into a circumference are regular, take for example a non-squared rectangle. But I do not know how to show that the other sentence is true or false. Is there a non-regular convex equilateral polygon that can be inscribed into a circumference? Or Every equilateral convex polygon inscribed to a circumference is a regular polygon?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The only type of rhombus that can be inscribed in a circle is square.

Any convex equilateral polygon inscribed in a circle must be regular

Comment: The size of the sides uniquely determines the interior angles. Thus equilateral implies equiangular, hence regular.

Comment: @GReyes Not true - rhombus example.  Need circle inscription.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Sure. I am implicitly assuming that it is inscribed, since the question is about those.

Comment: All chords of the same size have the same distance from the center, hence...